# Is there a way in firebase to get if email is verified?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

For now I'm doing like this:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (!user.emailVerified) {
      //Something
    }
});
```

But, the problem is I have added this block of code in multiple pages and whenever the authentication changed (user logged in or logged out) It calls all those functions and that effects other code!

**So, is there any way by which we get if users email is verified or not - without using 'onAuthStateChanged()'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere in your page you can do:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified
```

To determine the current state. You only need `onAuthStateChanged()` to monitor when the state changes.

Comment: Hello Frank, What if I verified an email and back to the same page of application and execute the same code? 

that still returning false; (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified = false)
Why do I need to Login again ? to get emailVerified true.

Comment: Hello, i can't find the method "emailVerified". Please can you help? I use this code:
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().....

Comment: For Android that information is under the provider data. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541887/firebase-how-to-detect-observe-when-firebase-user-verified-their-email-like-on ... is there any way to get this update reactively? Requiring polling seems very un-firebase.

Answer (score 0):

listener

```
onIdTokenChanged
```

to reload

```
auth.currentUser.reload()
auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)
```