# Firebase - How to detect/observe when Firebase user verified their email like onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I understand that to check if the user's email is verified, I can use

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    console.log(user["emailVerified"]);
})
```

However my problem is, I want to observe/listen and redirect to another page whenever the user verified their email address on their inbox.

Based on my testing, onAuthStateChanged is triggered when user logged in, updated their profile, and logged out, but is not triggered when the user verified their email address on their inbox.

Is there anyway I can detect when the user is verified and automatically redirect to another page?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to make it work through a setInterval function which checks the user's emailVerified property every second with the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
  firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
      console.log("Email Verified!");
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is a hack. Can the firebase people comment on why this isn't reactive like most other patterns in firebase?

Comment: Surely there is another way to check this?

Comment: Ugly hack, but I also do not see any other way right now. Sad that Firebase hasn't reacted to this.

Comment: any updates on a alternative approach on this one?

Comment: 4 years later and I also have to rely on this same "hack".

Comment: Just implemented this logic again. Is this still the hack to use? [@frank-van-puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) do you have any insights on how to implement this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

It's sad that firebase doesn't address this issue, I ended up holding a emailVerified flag on a firestore doc to sync state between open tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with checking `user` variable instead of calling `emailVerified()` function and wait for its response

```
this.authService.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user){
    if(user.emailVerified){
      //Verified
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also implemented this based on how I thought it would work, but it doesn't work. The state is not changed before a hard refresh is made.